# How to use a private git repo while building yocto using bitbake in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: git, ubuntu-16.04, yocto, bitbake

While using bitbake after configuring , bitbake failed before trying to clone/access a private repository using an SSH link .

```
$ bitbake linux-imx
git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 ls-remote ssh://git@gitlab.com:~/some-project/some-repo.git
| DEBUG: Python function base_do_fetch finished
| DEBUG: Python function do_fetch finished
| ERROR: Function failed: Fetcher failure: Fetch command failed with exit code 128, output:
| ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlab.com:~: Name or service not known
| fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
| 
| Please make sure you have the correct access rights
| and the repository exists.
| 
ERROR: Task 4 (/home/user/Projects/some_project/some-project-release-bsp/sources/meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-bsp/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-imx_4.1.15.bb, do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
```

When i try to remove the `~/` from the URL i get a similar error .

```
| DEBUG: Python function base_do_fetch finished
| DEBUG: Python function do_fetch finished
| ERROR: Function failed: Fetcher failure: Fetch command failed with exit code 128, output:
| ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlab.com:some-project: Name or service not known
| fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I even tried modifying the URL to https: , on which it gave me another error

```
git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 ls-remote http://gitlab.com/some-project/some-repo.git
| DEBUG: Python function base_do_fetch finished
| DEBUG: Python function do_fetch finished
| ERROR: Function failed: Fetcher failure: Fetch command failed with exit code 128, output:
| fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com': No such device or address
| 
ERROR: Task 4 (/home/user/Projects/some-project/some-project-release-bsp/sources/meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-bsp/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-imx_4.1.15.bb, do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
```

When i tried the same in the terminal instead of bitbake , It succeeded with the desired output

```
git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 ls-remote git@gitlab.com:some-project/some-repo.git
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 . I know that Yocto build is not tested in Ubuntu 16.04 .

```
WARNING: Host distribution "Ubuntu-16.04" has not been validated with this version of the build system; you may possibly experience unexpected failures. It is recommended that you use a tested distribution.
```

But a previous build with public repositories succeeded . So is there a way to make this work ?

Comment: Exactly how have you written your `SRC_URI`?

Comment: SRC_URI = "git://git@gitlab.com:~/some-project/some-repo.git;protocol=ssh;branch=${SRCBRANCH}"...... I tried changing the `~/` and also used `https://` . None of them worked !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using:

```
git://git@gitlab.com/some-project/some-repo.git;protocol=‌​ssh;branch=${SRCBRAN‌​CH}
```

in your SRC_URI.

Note the removal of `:~`.

Comment: I tried `git@gitlab.com/user/some-project/some-repo.git` resulting in an error `ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlab.com:user: Name or service not known` . I even tried `git@gitlab.com:user/some-project/some-repo.git` and `git@gitlab.com/~/some-project/some-repo.git` all resulting in the previous error .

Comment: And if this is of any help . I tried running `git clone ssh://git@gitlab.com:~/some-project/some-repo.git` in Ubuntu 14.04 , which worked . But the same command didnt work in Ubuntu 16.04 . Is this something related to versions of git , rather than yocto ?

Comment: `git://git@gitlab.com/some-project/some-repo.git;protocol=‌​ssh;branch=${SRCBRAN‌​CH}` worked . Thank you very much . If i may , Can i know what is the reason for this behaviour ?

Comment: I am getting error: 
`do_fetch: URL: 'git://git@gitlab.com/my_userame/my_repo.git;protocol=‌​ssh' has invalid parameters. Invalid protocol type` . What could be the problem, I have ssh installed on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

What you may want is a deploy token for your gitlab repo. I suspect github has something similar. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/.

Once you have created the token, you will have a token name, such as `gitlab+deploy-token-1` and the token itself, which is only displayed upon creation, such as `yN_gx3zzrrgqnxzzgsZmqS`.

Once you a have these values for your token, add it to your SRC_URI as a `user:pass` like so:

```
SRC_URI = "git://gitlab.com/my_username/my_repo.git;protocol=https;user=gitlab+deploy-token-1:yN_gx3zzrrgqnxzzgsZmqS;branch=master"
```

Note that anyone with access to this recipe will be able to clone your private repo. You can set an expiration date for the token, or manually revoke it at any time.

Answer (score 0):

It is something to do with how Yocto fetch the source code from `gitlab`.  No matter the repository is public or private, the git link will not work.

I have search a lot but do not find a reason. So, I had to move my repository to github. It will work when it switches to github.

An alternative way is to fetch your source to local and edit the recipe to source it from there.

Comment: The suggestion in the other comment seems to work with gitlab too .